# Recursively transposing a matrix in python natively

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how to transpose a matrix (represented as a list of lists) in Python using map and filter only recursively. I;ve tried various implementations and none of them work. Here's what I have currently:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return list(map(lambda x: [x], list(filter(lambda x: [0], matrix))))
```

All other answers using for loops and/or zip functions which is a restriction.

Any directions would be helpful too

Comment: @E.Coms: Not a duplicate, "recursively" is not a usual part of transposition, and not present in your link (even though OP doesn't have any recursion in their code?)

Comment: Yeah all the duplicates use some form or zip or for loop..

Comment: @blhsing see above

Comment: @blhsing Not a duplicate. He asked to transpose using *only* `lambda` and `filter`.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry about that. Reopened then.

Comment: Thanks! Anyone have any ideas on how I could go from here? I am thinking I must map through the nested lists with a filter inside that extracts each indexed positioned element although my execution is lacking..

Comment: @RockyLi I don't think it's only lambda and filter; I read it "using map and filter, only recursively" where "only" means "just" or "but". Then again, OP should likely clarify what the exact limits are. Note that there is no natural way to transpose a matrix recursively; it is possible, but cannot be particularly fast, I don't think.

Comment: @Amadan yes you're right, it just struck me as particularly interesting as a code golf kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda x: x[i], matrix)), range(len(matrix[0]))))
```

No `for` loop in this one.

Comment: Great but the OP asks for a recursive solution.

Comment: @ilovesports524 So recursion and `filter` aren't a requirement after all?

Comment: @blhsing yes you're right. I was only trying to do it without `for`, but looks like OP got what he wanted, maybe he should drop the recursive requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can map the first column of each row as a sub-list (to become a new row), and then recursively pass the rest of the matrix (without the first column) to the same process, until all rows are empty:

```
def transpose(m):
    return m and [list(map(lambda r: r[0], m)), *transpose(list(filter(len, map(lambda r: r[1:], m))))]
```

so that:

```
transpose([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
```

returns:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: Truly recursive, amazing.

Comment: Updated to return a list instead of a generator.